# My Google Maps add Things to do, resturants, etc

Tags: google-maps

Search high and low for how to add "things to do" or restaurants to a custom map I created using Google MyMaps.

Ex: Take the results of this link
https://www.google.com/maps/search/restaurants/@42.2557654,-86.3962214,9.71z

And add it as a layer to MyMap. I can search within mymaps for locations and add one by one, but I want to leverage what the results of google maps to show me all the restaurants in an area.

Backstory: I have 10 or so houses on a mymap, trying to overlay things to do in order to determine which house to buy :)